# How to reduce redundant repeated patterns in a string, but retain those at a latter position?

Tags: r, string, gsub

I'm trying to remove repeated patterns from a string, but retain those that are appearing at a latter position. 
Sadly I can't seem to do this through gsub without removing the patterns on a different position.

Basically I want to turn this:

```
"Place1-Place2-Place2-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5"
"Place1-Place1-Place1-Place1-Place3-Place5"
"Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place3-Place5-Place5"
```

Into this:

```
"Place1-Place2-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5"
"Place1-Place3-Place5"
"Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df <- c("Place1-Place2-Place2-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5",
        "Place1-Place1-Place1-Place1-Place3-Place5",
        "Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place3-Place5-Place5")

df_split <- as.data.table(str_split(df[1],"-"))
df[1] <- df_split %>% summarise(location=paste(unique(V1),collapse="-"))
df[1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some approaches.  No packages are used. (See Note at end for `s`.)

**1) gsub** Replace any substring of non-minuses that is followed by minus and itself with the empty string (where minus is replaced with the empty string too):

```
gsub("([^-]+)-(?=\\1)", "", s, perl = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Place1-Place2-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5"
[2] "Place1-Place3-Place5"                     
[3] "Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5"       
[4] "Place6"                                   
[5] "Place7"
```

**2) strsplit/paste**  Alternately split the strings, check for duplicates and paste back together giving the same answer:

```
undup_paste <- function(x) paste(x[c(TRUE, x[-1] != x[-length(x)])], collapse = "-")
sapply(strsplit(s, "-"), undup_paste)
```

**3) rle** This uses `strsplit` and `paste` as in (2) but the `x[...]` part is replaced with `rle` :

```
sapply(strsplit(s, "-"), function(x) paste(rle(x)$values, collapse = "-"))
```

**Note:** The input character vector `s` in reproducible form is:

```
s <- c("Place1-Place2-Place2-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place5",
       "Place1-Place1-Place1-Place1-Place3-Place5",
       "Place1-Place4-Place2-Place3-Place3-Place5-Place5",
       "Place6-Place6", 
       "Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7")
```

This is the same as `df` in the question except we have added two more components at the end suggested in the comments.

Comment: I've tried all three and it seems the gsub is failing to catch all patterns if there's only one present. for example s <- c("Place6-Place6",
        "Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7") The rest works flawlessly. I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I hope you could help out again. `gsub` is failing when a pattern has the same character/digit on the first and last part. Here's a sample data `s <- c("Place6-PPlace6", "Place7-Place7-Place7-7Place7-Place7-Place7-Place7")`

Comment: This is not really well specified.  Depending on what the expected answer is use (2) or (3) instead of (1).